# "The three shooters algorithm"

Tags: java, algorithm, probability

Like the title says, you've got 3 'shooters': shooter **A**, **B** and **C**.

The rules are the following:

Each one has a different chance to hit:

Shooter **A** will hit for **100%** of the times.

Shooter **B** will hit for **80%** of the times.

And shooter **C** will hit for **50%** of the times.

Each shooter will factually die after being hit once and will be removed.

Each shooter will prioritize hitting the shooter still alive with the highest chance to hit. f.e if all shooters are alive: **C** shoots **A**, **B** shoots **A**, **A** shoots **B**.

Each shooter may only shoot one bullet when it's his turn.

Each new game that starts will let one of the three shooters start at random.

Once a shooter played his turn (and if that shooter is not the only one left standing), the next shooter to play will be picked at random and the one who just played his turn can't be picked again(meaning that the shooter who just played can't play two turns consecutively but after the next turn he may play again).

A game can only end once there's a winner in the form of the last shooter standing.

_________________________________________________________________________

Now then, I was tasked with finding the average win ratio for each shooter after.. Lets say, 2,000,000 games.

My results were as following:

A: 0.2344525(23.4%), B: 0.3187745(31.8%), C: 0.446773(44.6%).

 we were given no formal answer in our class and just about everyone I checked up with came with a different answer of his own.

**Is my code for solving this scenario correct (in the form of providing me with the right answer)?**

```
public static char shooters(){
        char winner = 'x';//'x' means that there's no winner yet
        char a = 'v', b = 'v', c = 'v';//'v' means that they're alive
        double turn = Math.random()*3, shoot;
        /*turn:
          0 to 1 will always mean it's a's turn.
          1 to 2 will always mean it's b's turn.
          2 to 3 will always mean it's c's turn.
        */
        while(winner == 'x'){//winner will change to 'a', 'b' or 'c' upon ending
            if(turn < 1){//A starts (1.0)
                b = 'x';//b' is dead.
                turn = 2.5;//c's turn now.
            }else if(turn < 2){//B starts (0.8)
                shoot = Math.random();
                if(shoot <= 0.8){//b hits
                    if(a == 'v' && c == 'v'){//both opponents alive, a goes down
                        a = 'x';//a' is dead.
                        turn = 2.5;//c's turn now.
                    }else{
                        winner = 'b';//whatever the case, b will hit the last competitor left.
                    }
                }else{//b misses
                    if(a == 'v' && c == 'v'){
                        turn = Math.random()*2;
                        if(turn >= 1){//since we can't let b' play the next turn consecutively:
                            turn++;//adjust to represent c's turn instead of b's.
                        }
                    }else{
                        turn = 2.5;//c's turn, since a is dead.
                    }
                }
            }else{//C starts (0.5)
                shoot = Math.random();
                if(shoot <= 0.5){//c hits
                    if(a == 'v' && b == 'v'){//both opponents alive, a goes down
                        a = 'x';//a' is dead.
                        turn = 1.5;//b's turn now.
                    }else{
                        winner = 'c';//whatever the case, c will hit the last competitor left.
                    }
                }else{//c misses
                    if(a == 'v' && b == 'v'){
                        turn = Math.random()*2;
                    }else if(a == 'v'){
                        winner = 'a';//a's turn since b is dead which leads to c dying.
                    }else{
                        turn = 1.5;//b's turn, since a' is dead.
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return winner;
    }
```

Comment: You should share your approach on how you got these results, so we can tell you if your approach is correct. (And yes, it's not exactly the right place to ask this question, but it's interesting enough, so wait and see where it goes.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a problem in probability and should be asked on [maths.se]

Comment: Do the shooters have equal chance of starting? If yes, the probability for a winning should be at least 33%. On the other hand, your code seems to weight the starting shooter. Which is correct?

Comment: They do indeed have equal chance of starting, but then, for the end result, you'd have to consider the fact shooter a' is up against the 2 other shooters, since both of them will prioritize shooting a' as long as it's still standing.

Comment: the code could certainly use some optimization, plus some amount of effort is required to "decode" your logic (e.g. `turn = 1.5;` and `a = 'x';`)

Comment: True, this code was originally meant for me alone to view or then others with me personally explaining it step by step, so my apologies about that :) I'll add some more comments in a bit to make it easier to read.

Comment: How comes this question was put on hold? The OP demonstrated how it's meant to be solved programmatically with his/her own code. One could argue that this question belongs in Mathematics, but then, it also belongs here...

Comment: FYI, my calculations give approximately 23.5% for a, 31.9% for b, 44.59% for c, so your results seem perfectly correct.

Comment: The exact values are 165/702 for a (23.50%), 224/702 for b (31.91%), 313/702 for c (44.59%). I found the fractions by hand, so there might be mistakes, but granted how it matches your results, we can be pretty confident.

Comment: @Joffrey Can you please post the equations you used to get those values in an answer?

Comment: @Shashank sure, but it'll take a while to copy the whole thing

Comment: @Shashank Actually I can't post an answer because the question has been closed. Maybe I can answer if the question is asked on the math forum.

Comment: @Joffrey Hmm, its a shame. Because I came up with the probability of A winning and my answer shows that the probability is slightly > 0.2375. I would have liked to compare my answer with yours and see how you got 0.2350 (for just A...) Anyways these problems are hard for me since they involve an infinite series. I remember basic probability but I forgot how to do that infinite series arithmetic. There's some statistical formula for it, I'm sure.

Comment: @Shashank here is a google doc detailing my calculus (still in edition): https://docs.google.com/document/d/1y4qLWWECj0kJnxm8Q6u__2594Su1WYRRz0tKdfAExH8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What if `B` is dead and `A` shoots? (Please stick to capital letters for names.)

Comment: @greybeard then A shoots C, what's the problem?

Comment: @Joffre Correct, A will then shoot C, your calculations provided through that link seem pretty reassuring, good to know I'm probably the only one in my class who did it right then :D Is there a way to pass this question to a different forum then so that we can use your answer? Or what would you guys suggest?

Comment: @NerdOnline I believe the math stackexchange forum would be appropritate if you formulate the question like "do these results seem correct?"

Comment: @Joffrey Thanks for posting, I haven't had time to read over your calculations but I will soon. I want to see where I messed up.

Comment: @NerdOnline please comment here with a link to your new question if you do post on a new forum, so that I can write my answer outside of a google doc :-)

Comment: @MrGuy I agree, because the question cqn be formulated this way "my results seem wrong to me, do you see any problem in the program?"

Comment: @Joffrey hm, good point actually, gonna try editting this post to work that way then :p On the meanwhile though: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1196734/the-three-shooters-algorithm - sorry that it took so long :)